# Regrouping Multimap Elements

Tags: java, guava, multimap

Is there a way to regroup guava multimap elements. For example let's assume that  we have this multimap :

```
Multimap<String, Integer> testMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
testMultimap.put("key1", 15);
testMultimap.put("key2", 12);
testMultimap.put("key1", 20);
```

And we want to get the sum of every multimap's key elements. So is there a guava way to handle this and get a simple result map like this :

```
resultMap => "Key1": 35, "Key2": 12
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it, i could do it like this :

```
Function<Collection<Integer>, Number> additionFunction = new Function<Collection<Integer>, Number>() {
    @Override
    public Number apply(Collection<Integer> numbers) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Integer number : numbers) {
            sum += number; 
        }
        return sum;
    }
};

Maps.transformValues(testMultimap.asMap(), additionFunction);
```

**PS :**  The advantage of using the guava way here, is that we could define multiple functions and then switch between them easily throw the interface `Function<Collection<Integer>, Number>`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using wrong collection in first place - instead of `Multimap` you should use [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v15.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html). From [Guava Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset):

> Guava provides a new collection type, Multiset, which supports adding
>   multiples of elements. Wikipedia defines a multiset, in mathematics,
>   as “a generalization of the notion of set in which members are allowed
>   to appear more than once...In multisets, as in sets and in contrast to
>   tuples, the order of elements is irrelevant: The multisets `{a, a, b}`
>   and `{a, b, a}` are equal.”
>
> There are two main ways of looking at this:
>
> - This is like an `ArrayList<E>` without an ordering constraint: ordering does not matter.
> - **This is like a `Map<E, Integer>`, with elements and counts.**

With `Multiset` your example will be:

```
Multiset<String> bag = HashMultiset.create();
bag.add("key1", 15);
bag.add("key2", 12);
bag.add("key1", 20);
```

And then bag will contain 35 occurences of "key1" and 12 occurences of "key2", i.e. `bag.toString()` will be `{ key1 x 35, key2 x 12 }`. (Use [`LinkedHashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v15.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultiset.html) if you want preserve order of keys).

Comment: I don't think that's a good solution, it's limited to addition operations. See my response, it's more generic.

Comment: Have you checked Multiset API? It implements JDK's [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), so `remove(Object)`, `removeAll(Collection<?>)` and `Multiset`'s `remove(Object, int)` methods are present in `Multiset`.

Comment: I'm not speaking about multiset's operations, i'm speaking about the operation of regroupment, in my example it's an addition, but what if i want to change it to a multiplication. Another time, see my response and not my question

Comment: Original question was about specific use case and possible general solution with Guava; what you've added makes it much more narrow use case (implementing mathematical operations on data, which, in that case, shouldn't be stored with Multimap) and not general collection question.

Comment: May be my question was not so clear, but me i just wanted to know if there was a way to regroup a multimap's key elements with a given transformation. I gave a quick addition use case, just to clarify the question. Anyway, thank you for your interesting suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each key of the Multimap yields a collection, so you can iterate over it, get the sum of the elements and put that in another map.

I haven't tested because I don't have the Apache Common library at hand, but something similar should work.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    Set<String> keys = testMultiMap.keySet();
    for(String key : keys){
        Collection<Integer> coll = (Collection<Integer>) testMultiMap.get(key);
        int sum = 0;
        for(Integer i : coll){
            sum += i;
        }
        resultMap.put(key, sum);
    }
```

Comment: I know that i could do that, by i want to know if there is a guava way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadoc : http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html,
I'm not sure that there is another way ti initialize your map.

But you can do somthing with this :

```
static final Map<String, Integer> testMap  = ImmutableMap.of(
        "key1", 15,
        "key2", 12
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Multimap<String, Integer> data = ArrayListMultimap.create();
data.put("Alex", 10);
data.put("Tom", 20);
data.put("sirmagid", 30);
data.put("sirmagid", 31);

HashMap<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Set<String> keys = data.keySet();
for(String key : keys){
    Collection<Integer> coll = (Collection<Integer>) data.get(key);
    int sum = 0;
    for(Integer i : coll){
        sum += i;
    }
    resultMap.put(key, sum);
}


for (Map.Entry entry : resultMap.entrySet())
{    
System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + "; value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

[lib google guava](https://github.com/google/guava)